# Is there any way to hook the "controller" generator so it runs "rspec_controller"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to make it so I can just type `script/generate controller` and it will run `script/generate rspec_controller`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want it:

1. to *also* run `script/generate rspec_controller`, ***or***
2. to *only* run `script/generate rspec_controller`?

If `1` then you have multiple options.  The simplest and less intrusive would probably be to simply wrap `script/generate` as follows:

1. rename `script/generate` as `script/generate.orig`
2. create `script/generate` anew with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   "`dirname \"$0\"`/generate.orig" "$@"
   if [ "$1" == "controller" ] ; then
     shift
     "`dirname \"$0\"`/generate.orig" rspec_controller "$@"
   fi
   ```
3. ensure the new `script/generate` is executable etc., e.g. `chmod a+rx script/generate`
4. add `script/generate.orig` to source control and checkin the modified `script/generate` script